# Enum Numeric value in Case : Swift 3

Tags: swift, enums

In my scenario I want to use numeric value as enum case key value. How can I achieve that?

I tried

```
enum Order: String {
 case "1" : "Mobiles"
 case "2" : "Automotive"
}
```

Is there a way to write similar code?

I know other way works fine (case mobiles : "1" , case automotive : "2" ) but i need in this fashion.

Comment: You may get better answers if you update your question with some information about how you plan to use this enum and explain why you want numbers for the cases.

Comment: Why don't you have a `const immutable dictionary` of type `[Int:String]`

Comment: @rmaddy: I have an enum enum Product : String {

Comment: @Jack Sorry, but your comment makes no sense and doesn't remotely answer the question I asked. [Edit] your question with a clear description of why you want an enum with numbers. Show an example of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want, but you could do something like this:

```
enum Order: String {
 case order1 : "Mobiles"
 case order2 : "Automotive"
}
```

Or you could simply use a static array of strings:

```
struct Constants
{
  static let orders = ["Mobiles","Automotive"]
}
```

And subscript it with a numeric value :

```
Constants.orders[1]
```